# Communication between groupcache's peers not working

Tags: http, go, caching

I execute a local process with a group, and as expected first time it retrieves the data and keeps it in memory for the rest queries that ask for the same data. Everything is fine there.

If I run a different process registered as a peer if I asked for any data in one of those, I expected that the other one doesn't need to go to the database to retrieve it since the first one already did, but now, even if I already ask for the data in one of the peers the other one goes to the database and retrieve the data again. Shouldn't exist some kind of communication between the two peers? Why does it always go to the database if the other peers already loaded the same data?